# Google Sheets - How to retrieve a value from a range in one sheet to use in a formula on another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Sheet A I have something like the following:

| Apples | Oranges | Grapes | Bananas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15% | 20% | 25% | 40% |
| 228 | 304 | 380 | 608 |

In Sheet B I have the following:

| Price | Apples | Oranges | Grapes | Bananas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $0.15 | formula | formula | formula | formula |
| $0.72 | formula | formula | formula | formula |

In Sheet B, where I have written "formula" above, I want to have a formula that takes the value in the "Price" column for that row and multiples it by the corresponding percentage value for the header from Sheet A. For example, in the first "formula" in Sheet B under Apples I would have `=A2*('SheetA' vLookup 'Apples' A2:Z2)`

In this particular example I would expect the result to be $0.15*0.15=0.0225. Using the same formula, Sheet B should result with:

| Price | Apples | Oranges | Grapes | Bananas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $0.15 | 0.0225 | 0.03 | 0.0375 | 0.06 |
| $0.72 | 0.108 | 0.144 | 0.18 | 0.288 |

Edit for additional detail: The formula must search the header in the first sheet range because the positions in Sheet A are not static and may change. So for example, today the "Apples" percent may be Sheet A, B2 and tomorrow it may be in Sheet A, D2. It will always be in the same row (2), but not always in the same column. It will always have the same header in both sheets, so as long as it finds "Apples" in Sheet A, the next cell in row 2 will be the correct percent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following in `SheetB!B2`:

```
=HLOOKUP(B$1, SheetA!$A$1:$2, 2, FALSE)*$A2
```

You'll actually want to use `HLOOKUP` instead of `VLOOKUP`, since you're searching a row horizontally instead of a column. You can then drag/copy the formula to all the relevant cells on `SheetB`.

Answer (score 0):

here's an arrayformula approach:

```
=index(A7:A8*VLookup(B6:E6,split(flatten(A1:D1&"❆"&A2:D2),"❆"),2,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

any reason why not use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A2:D3*A7:A8)
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(A6:A7*HLOOKUP(B5:E5, A1:D2, 2, ))
```

[image]

Comment: That doesn't produce the correct output for row 8. It seems like the intention is that each price value is multiplied by the percentage in row 2, not a row relative to the price cell. `=ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A3*SheetA!A2:D2)` seems like a better solution to lock the second factor to the one row with percentages.

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue at all. For one, B2 has no relation to B8 in my example while your formula is multiplying them for the value. The values in B8:E8 would be the same as B7:E7 but multiplied by A8 instead of A7. The second issue is that the sheets are different so it would need to find the correct values from the first sheet, which isn't static, hence why I need it to vLookup in a range to find the correct percentage to multiply against.

Comment: @o_O answer updated. next time try to provide a more sophisticated example of your data ample, tho.